# Функция substr неправильно "режет" строку

Tags: php, строки

Есть строка НА КИРИЛЛИЦЕ, извлеченная из БД, которую нужно урезать на n символов. Сопоставление(collation) - utf8-general-ci. Кодировка utf8. Пишу код:

```
echo substr($string, 0, 20);
```

Выводит 10 символов. Логически рассуждая один символ берется за два, НО "пробел" - за один. 
Что делать???

Comment: кажеться нашел решение - mb_substr()

Comment: мой вариант попробуйте. Он Вам точно должен помочь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте функции для работы со строками, поддерживающие многобайтные кодировки. например `echo mb_substr($string, 0, 20);`

Comment: mb_internal_encoding действует только на mb_ функции

Comment: использую одну mb_substr() и все правильно работает. еще смотрю ей(функции) в 4 аргументе можно передать кодировку. спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй так:

```
echo mb_substr($string, 0, 20, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Answer (score -1):

Переводить кирилицу в юникод, резать в юникоде, переводить обратно в кирилицу.

ps отказаться от кириллицы навсегда - использовать юникод :)

Comment: Оно ж и так в юникоде. Написано же: 

> Сопоставление(collation) - utf8-general-ci. Кодировка utf8

Comment: а разве utf8 не юникод? кириллица в смысле - русские буквы

Answer (score -1):

В юникоде русские буквы - 2 байта, латинские и пробел - 1 байт. Высчитывай длину строки в байтах и вызывай substr с этим числом.

Comment: а не лучше использовать mb функции?

Comment: русские да а вот пробел(space) - 1 байт. вот и гадайте-считайте где вам пробел попадется ,)